# Assigning / partitioning empty disk space

Tags: partitioning, storage

I have a 500gb hard drive on my ubuntu server.  I partitioned 150GB for the OS and anything that needs to run on the server (websites, APIs, whatever), and left the other 350GB for backups of important network resources.

My question is, how can I ***use*** that empty disk space so that I can mount it and copy gzipped files there from my network?

I don't need any networking help, just need to know how to create another partition my hard drive that will be used only for storage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no consideration for SCSI controllers or volume management - just a disk in a computer...

First find the device name for the disk:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Let's assume you learn the device name is **sda**. Next, create a partition:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

- Type **p** to print a list of existing partitions.
- Type **m** for a list of commands.
- Type **n** to create a new partition
- Type **p** to indicate a primary partition
- Press **ENTER** to accept the default partition number
- Press **ENTER** to accept the default starting sector
- Press **ENTER** to accept the default ending sector
- Type **p** again to print a list of partitions
- Is it correct? Type **w** to write the change.
- Type **q** to quit.

Let's assume the new partition has the device name, sda3, and you want an ext3 filesystem:

```
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda3
```

Let's assume you want to mount in /mnt/backup:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/backup
```

Let's assume you want to automatically mount the file system at boot time:

```
sudo -e /etc/fstab
```

Add to the contents of /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda3    /mnt/backup    ext3    defaults    0    1
```

And then mount it manually because we have not rebooted:

```
sudo mount /mnt/backup
```

Success?